# On automatic language detection in Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech

Tags: c#, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

We're experimenting with the automatic language detection feature in Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech. Our test case is to transcribe a live Norwegian news broadcast, where some VBs may be in other languages, e.g. from the ongoing impeachment trial in the US. We had great results when broadcasting live from the entire opening of the trial, but with shorter English language VBs in the middle of a Norwegian news broadcast, the recognizer fails to detect that the language has changed, with rather incomprehensible results (naturally).

My question is, what does it take for the SpeechRecognizer to detect a change in source language in such cases? Is there anything we can do to improve this behavior? If we could make this work reliably, it would improve our results dramatically.

Thanks in advance for any hints/tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SpeechRecognizer can't yet recognize language switches in an audio, this will be added in the near future.

Comment: Any news/ETA on this? In our live transcription tests we notice that the detected language does change mid-stream now and then, but not reliably yet.

Answer (score 1):

One of the requirements for shorter audio utterances is that they need to have at least 5 seconds of human speech before the language detection can do a reasonable job at estimating the spoken language.